# Извлечь данные из html атрибута

Tags: flutter, dart

В html-атрибуте приходят сериализованные данные. Необходимо их извлечь и декодировать для дальнейшей работы с ними.
Мои попытки не увенчались успехом - на выходе получаю строку.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String str =
      '<App menudata="[{&quot;id&quot;:4,&quot;parent_id&quot;:0,&quot;route_name&quot;:null,&quot;element_name&quot;:null,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;\/admin\/support\/&quot;}]" content="{}" route_name="" ></App>';
  Pattern pattern = r'"\[.{0,}\]"';
  RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
  str = str.replaceAll('&quot;', '\'');
  str = regex.stringMatch(str);
  var decodeDate = jsonDecode(str);
  print(decodeDate);
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/2727ebdc830a56acac6f1c82bac896d3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас JSON был невалидным, исправил:

```
void main() {
  String str =
      '<App menudata="[{&quot;id&quot;:4,&quot;parent_id&quot;:0,&quot;route_name&quot;:null,&quot;element_name&quot;:null,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;\/admin\/support\/&quot;}]" content="{}" route_name="" ></App>';
  Pattern pattern = r'\[.{0,}\]';
  RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
  str = str.replaceAll('&quot;', '\"');
  str = regex.stringMatch(str);
  print(str);
  var decodeDate = json.decode(str);
  print(decodeDate.runtimeType);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю!.....